Ubuntu 24.04.1 can not hibernate after update from 22.04
uname -a:
I update kernel because this is ROG laptop, and the products of https://asus-linux.org/ needs 6.10 kernel.
Linux sysescool-G614JVR 6.10.7-061007-generic #202408291638 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Aug 29 16:58:34 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I follow this website: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/ and this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1769297 and others.
I create /swap.img by:
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap.img bs=1MB count=102400 status=progress
sudo chmod 600 /swap.img
sudo mkswap /swap.img
sudo swapon /swap.img

sudo vim /etc/fstab:
/swap.img      none     swap   sw   0    0

swapon --show:
NAME      TYPE  SIZE USED PRIO
/swap.img file 95.4G   0B   -2

free -h:
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62Gi       5.4Gi        54Gi       945Mi       4.1Gi        56Gi
Swap:           95Gi          0B        95Gi

sudo filefrag -v /swap.img | head --lines=5:
Filesystem type is: ef53
File size of /swap.img is 102400000000 (25000000 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..    2047:  941064192.. 941066239:   2048:            
   1:     2048..    4095:   25516032..  25518079:   2048:  941066240:

lsblk:
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
....... loop 1 - 19 .......
loop20        7:20   0 321.1M  1 loop /snap/vlc/3777
nvme1n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme1n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p3 259:3    0 926.3G  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p4 259:4    0   1.1G  0 part 
├─nvme1n1p5 259:5    0    26G  0 part 
└─nvme1n1p6 259:6    0   260M  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:7    0   3.7T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:8    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:9    0   513M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p3 259:10   0   3.7T  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                      /

sudo blkid /dev/nvme0n1p3:
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="cbc32cab-155d-47cd-a8c6-63e5bf5dd1c9" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="447ea4d7-c4b4-400f-bc11-d150875a7979"

sudo vim /etc/default/grub:
................
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=cbc32cab-155d-47cd-a8c6-63e5bf5dd1c9 resume_offset=941064192"
................

sudo update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.10.7-061007-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.10.7-061007-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme1n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume:
resume=UUID=cbc32cab-155d-47cd-a8c6-63e5bf5dd1c9 resume_offset=941064192

sudo update-initramfs -c -k all:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.10.7-061007-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-45-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic

sudo vim /sys/power/resume:
259:10

sudo vim /etc/tmpfiles.d/hibernation_resume.conf:
#    Path                   Mode UID  GID  Age Argument
w    /sys/power/resume       -    -    -    -   259:10

sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf add below:
blacklist intel_hid

reboot and try sudo systemctl hibernate:
The laptop indeed try to hibernate: the disk light flash, keyboard light turns off.
But after seconds then return log in window. it does not shutdown.
Log in it, all the things before hibernate keep it.
sudo systemctl status systemd-hibernate.service:
○ systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2024-09-26 11:56:21 CST; 42min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-hibernate.service(8)
    Process: 5729 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep hibernate (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 5729 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1.527s

9 26 11:56:11 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Starting systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate...
9 26 11:56:11 sysescool-G614JVR systemd-sleep[5729]: Performing sleep operation 'hibernate'...
9 26 11:56:21 sysescool-G614JVR systemd-sleep[5729]: System returned from sleep operation 'hibernate'.
9 26 11:56:21 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Deactivated successfully.
9 26 11:56:21 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Finished systemd-hibernate.service - System Hibernate.
9 26 11:56:21 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: systemd-hibernate.service: Consumed 1.527s CPU time.

I really need this hibernate function, because I have mobile office needs with my laptop.
Thanks for reading, I would really appreciate it if you could give me some advice.
As user david asked df:
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             6545680      8616    6537064   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 3936314864 471189812 3265096432  13% /
tmpfs            32728384     73792   32654592   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120        12       5108   1% /run/lock
efivarfs              192       143         45  77% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme1n1p1     262144    109760     152384  42% /boot/efi
tmpfs             6545676      2644    6543032   1% /run/user/1000

mokutil --sb:
SecureBoot disabled

journalctl --since "2024-09-26 11:54" --until "2024-09-26 11:57" -k -p emerg..err:
9 26 11:56:21 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: Non-boot CPUs are not disabled
9 26 11:56:22 sysescool-G614JVR kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination

journalctl --since "2024-09-26 11:54" --until "2024-09-26 11:57":
It's too long, see: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/YTh6WjSPhK/
journalctl --since "2024-09-26 11:50" --until "2024-09-26 12:00" -k -p emerg..err:
-- No entries --

turn off Zoom function, try hibernate but still return log in window.
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service:
Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable bluetooth
Removed "/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service".
Removed "/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service".

then run sudo systemctl hibernate still come back to log in window.
and now journalctl --since "2024-09-28 00:20" --until "2024-09-28 00:22": https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9dzyGDKwhW/
is the critical log as below ?
9月 28 00:21:04 sysescool-G614JVR systemd-logind[943]: Operation 'hibernate' finished.
9月 28 00:21:04 sysescool-G614JVR asusd[1275]: [INFO  asusd::ctrl_platform] RogPlatform reloading panel_od
9月 28 00:21:04 sysescool-G614JVR NetworkManager[998]: <info>  [1727454064.9043] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
9月 28 00:21:04 sysescool-G614JVR NetworkManager[998]: <info>  [1727454064.9045] device (enp108s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
9月 28 00:21:04 sysescool-G614JVR ModemManager[1108]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
9月 28 00:21:04 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
9月 28 00:21:04 sysescool-G614JVR systemd[1]: Stopped target hibernate.target - System Hibernation.

I notice there is a asusd, then I run sudo systemctl stop asusd and try to hibernate but still come back to log in window.
hibernate failed then run sudo dmidecode -t system | grep -P '\tWake-up Type\: ':
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch

sudo dmidecode -t system
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.6.0 present.
# SMBIOS implementations newer than version 3.5.0 are not
# fully supported by this version of dmidecode.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: ROG Strix G16 G614JVR_G614JVR
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: RANRKD01181043F
    UUID: fb4377e0-91c0-3947-b687-29a863a7430f
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number:  
    Family: ROG Strix G16

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: Default string

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected


cat /proc/acpi/wakeup after sudo systemctl hibernate:
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEG1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
RP09      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP10      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP11      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP12      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP13      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP14      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP15      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP16      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP01      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:6c:00.0
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP17      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP18      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP19      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP20      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP21      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP22      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP23      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP24      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP25      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP26      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP27      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP28      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
XDCI      S4    *disabled
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
CNVW      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.3
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00

cat /proc/acpi/wakeup after sudo systemctl suspend:
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEG1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.0  # PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a70d (rev 01)
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
RP09      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP10      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP11      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP12      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP13      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP14      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP15      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP16      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP01      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0  # PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a3d (rev 11)
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:6c:00.0  # Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP17      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP18      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP19      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP20      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP21      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP22      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP23      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP24      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP25      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0  # PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #25 (rev 11)
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0  # PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
RP26      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP27      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP28      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
XHCI      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0  # USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 (20 Gb/s) XHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
XDCI      S4    *disabled
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3  # Audio device: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake High Definition Audio Controller (rev 11)
CNVW      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.3  # Network controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00

lspci:
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device a702 (rev 01)
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a70d (rev 01)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S UHD Graphics (rev 04)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 01)
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller Intel Corporation
0000:00:13.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7a79 (rev 11)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake USB 3.2 Gen 2x2 (20 Gb/s) XHCI Host Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S PCH Shared SRAM (rev 11)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Serial IO I2C Host Controller #0 (rev 11)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake CSME HECI #1 (rev 11)
0000:00:1a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #25 (rev 11)
0000:00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a3d (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a0c (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake High Definition Audio Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-S PCH SMBus Controller (rev 11)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake SPI (flash) Controller (rev 11)
0000:02:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:03:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 1133 (rev 02)
0000:04:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 1134
0000:38:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 1135
0000:6c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
10000:e0:1b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation RST VMD Managed Controller
10000:e0:1b.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev 11)
10000:e0:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation RST VMD Managed Controller
10000:e0:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a34 (rev 11)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: MAXIO Technology (Hangzhou) Ltd. NVMe SSD Controller MAP1602 (DRAM-less) (rev 01)
10000:e2:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Platinum P41/PC801 NVMe Solid State Drive

Disable RP25 by su then echo RP25 > /proc/acpi/wakeup:



ls pci
1(from power on)
2(login from 1)
3(resume from 2)
4(lgoin from 3)
5(resume from 4)
6(login from 5)




PXSX with 6c
0
0
0
0
0
0


RP25
0
0
0
0
0
0


PXSX with 02
1
diable and no pci
1
disable and no pci
1
disable and no pci


RESULT
turn back login window
hibernate success
turn back login window
long time black screen, no turn back login in, no shutdown. long press power button to shutdown
turn back login window
long time black screen, no turn back login in, no shutdown. long press power button to shutdown



If I just power on or resume run cat /proc/acpi/wakeup, there is PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0.
Once I hibernate failed and return to login window and run cat /proc/acpi/wakeup: the PXSX     S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0 change to PXSX      S4    *disabled
I can only hibernate success when RP25 diabled(by echo RP25 > wakeup) and PXSX   S4    *disabled.
However I can hibernate success the first time.
The other hibernate I will in black screen, no turnback login, no shutdown, but power light open state, and I have to long press power button to force shutdown.
Fortunately， If I wait black screen enough time, it hibernate indeed, and resume the next time. If I wait black screen short time, after force shuwdown, it's not resume, it's just power on and lost everything.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
